# How to inverse this logic definition of separator of Set category?

Tags: logic, category-theory

Lawvere's *Sets for Mathematics* defines a separator object $S$ for morphisms $f_1, f_2: X \rightarrow Y$ of the Set category as a logic statement $s$

$s$:

$\forall x \left[ S \xrightarrow{x} X \Rightarrow f_1 \circ x = f_2 \circ x\right] \Rightarrow f_1 = f_2$

Some proof exercises in the book are easier to start with considering morphisms that are not equal $f_1 \neq f_2$.  How to invert the above statement $s$ logically?

Is it

$\bar{s}_1$:

$f_1 \neq f_2 \Rightarrow \exists x \left[S \xrightarrow{x} X \Rightarrow f_1 \circ x \neq f_2 \circ x\right]$

?

Somehow I feels it's more "natural" to substitute the "$\Rightarrow$" symbols in the square brackets by "and" or "such that".  Do I miss some concepts in logic that might make me feel this way?   (My knowledge in logic is whatever I learned from high school maths and remains now.)

EDIT:

$\bar{s}_2$:

$f_1 \neq f_2 \land \exists x \left[S \xrightarrow{x} X \land f_1 \circ x \neq f_2 \circ x\right]$

EDIT 2:

$\bar{s}_3$:

$f_1 \neq f_2 \Rightarrow \exists x \left[S \xrightarrow{x} X \land f_1 \circ x \neq f_2 \circ x\right]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The denial of $p \Rightarrow q$ is not, as you seem to have it, $p \Rightarrow \lnot q$, but instead it's $p \land (\lnot q).$ So it seems your statement after "Is it" would be correct if you replaced the $\Rightarrow$ in it by a conjunction symbol $\land$.

Comment: There're two $\Rightarrow$'s in it, which one should be replaced by $\land$?

Comment: There is only one $\Rightarrow$, the other arrow is part of $S\xrightarrow{x} x.$ This other arrow with the $x$ over it is not a logical connective but a predicate.

Comment: The second "$\Rightarrow$" is after $X$.

Comment: Oh I thought you already knew that is the one. In your added statement you call $\bar{s}_2,$ the first $\Rightarrow$ comes by taking the contrapositive of what you call statement $s$, and is naturally correct. So to answer your comment, it's the second $\Rightarrow$ in $\bar{s}_2$ which should be replaced by $\land.$

Comment: Now, I'm confused.  You said above "it's the second $\Rightarrow$ in $\bar{s}_2$".  But $\bar{s}_2$ only has ONE $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: Is $\bar{s}_3$ the correct answer?

Comment: @Problemaniac Yes. That is it, using the logic of contrapositive plus the denial of the $\Rightarrow$ inside the square brackets of the original statement $s.$